# Call meteor logout when browser is closed

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is there a way to detect in javascript when the browser closes. I want to on browser close, call `Meteor.logout()` for the existing user and run a clean up. Does anyone know of any particular hooks that are cross compatible.

Comment: Why do you need the logout function to be called? What does your clean up look like? Give the inherent cross-browser incompatibility issues that you are going to run into I would suggest a background-task that handles this specific case, but I would need some more context to make any proper recommendations.

Comment: @johnsel - "Why do you need the logout function to be called" - Hard to explain both in a comment and in the context of a SO question since it's very specific to the type of application being built, ['security reasons', 'business reasons', ...]. I guess I was asking at a high level if there is a javascript hook when a browser closes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [user-status](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status) package which provides hooks and collections for detecting connections, and users logging in out out.

Full disclosure: I maintain this package.

Comment: thanks for the package reference, I couldn't tell directly from the README but was there a particular hook I was suppose to be looking for. I can browse through the source code if you can start me at a particular location.

Comment: there isn't warz, the user-status package is useless for logging users out on window close because the hooks get called on refresh, whenever the user refreshes the page, the user will get logged out. You'll need to look at other packages or figure out a way to roll your own.